# How to update a column by running max() on the same column?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have three rows of data:

```
temp_number        tempdate
A12345              null
A12345001          '2018-01-01'
A12345002          '2018-01-02'
```

I want to set tempdate on `A12345` to `2018-01-02` using this query:

```
update table_a1 set tempdate = (select max(tempdate) from table_a1 where 
substr(temp_number,1,6) = 'A12345')
where temp_number = 'A12345'
```

The query above is not working, and I want to update the value by using a `max()` function rather than giving any actual value.

Comment: Do you really only intend to do a single update here?  Is there a more general logic?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you could use a join  on subquery for max value

```
update table_a1 m
INNER JOIN (
    select max(tempdate)  max_date, substr(temp_number,1,6) temp1
    from table_a1 
    where substr(temp_number,1,6) = 'A12345')
    group by temp
) t on t.temp1 =  m.tempdate 
set tempdate = t.max_date
```

Answer (score 1):

Your `WHERE` clause is wrong, and you should be updating only `NULL` records:

```
UPDATE table_a1
SET tempdate = (SELECT MAX(tempdate)
                FROM table_a1
                WHERE temp_number LIKE 'A12345%')
WHERE temp_number = 'A1234' AND tempdate IS NULL;
```